# Connection to Mysql DB VB.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, function, connection

I created some code to connect to a mysql DB. everything works but I have created the same code several times in different forms.
I would like to create a function or a sub to be called instead of always writing the same connection lines.
Could you help me?
thanks

Comment: Create a class with a method which encapsulates your code. Preferably declare it `Shared` so you don´t need an object instance to call it.
Call that method wherever you´d like to. Pretty basic programming stuff.

Comment: Would be helpful if you post your code

Comment: A connection string can be globally available in the app.config (`My.Settings`) but do not make a globally available connection object. Connections need to be closed and disposed (see `Using` blocks). They should be declared in the method where they are used.

Comment: @AlexB. Yes, basic programming. But do not use this for connection objects.

Comment: @Mary I did not say he should create a global connection object. But it can be useful to have a global function which can create a disposable connection. I agree with the `using` point.

Comment: what is wrong with `using var conn = DBConnector.CreateConnection() ... end using` ?

Comment: @AlexB. Correct. It is just a matter of where the New keyword is and the As. Seems like there is not much point  but how is the New connection where it is created in the function disposed?

Comment: I got your point but I still don´t see a problem in disposing an object in a different method from where it is created. I use this since years for creating and disposing Entity Framwork contexts and never had any trouble.